# add onclick event to dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, onclick

I've been working on a functionality that involves the creation of a HTML table using jquery that will display a list of accounts dynamically on page load, that's something I achieved without problems.

However, I've also asked to add an "onclick" event to each row that will redirect me to another web page, but that will depend on a parameter that I need to pass. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var x = ['Visa-1234', 'Amex-9182', 'Visa-8162', 'Visa-9554'];
            var message = 'No accounts found';

            if (x.length > 0) {
                message = 'Select an account to display the rewards information: ';
            }

            $('#message').text(message);

            var tableContentHtml = '<table class="table-fill"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Account</th></tr></thead><tbody class="table-hover">';

            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tableContentHtml += '<tr><td class="text-left" onclick="goAnotherWebPage()">' + x[i] + '</td></tr>';
            }

            tableContentHtml += '</tbody></table>';
            $(tableContentHtml).appendTo('#container');
        });

        function goAnotherWebPage(account) {
            //do some logic here
        }
```

The method "goAnotherWebPage" should receive the same account ID that is being displayed, I have no problem with that, the problem comes when I pass the x[i] as parameter on the table creation:

```
onclick="goAnotherWebPage(x[i])"
```

That is not working, it says that the account is not defined.

Can somebody give me a hint or provide help in order to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  tableContentHtml += '<tr><td class="text-left" onclick="goAnotherWebPage(\'' + x[i] + '\')">' + x[i] + '</td></tr>';
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = ['Visa-1234', 'Amex-9182', 'Visa-8162', 'Visa-9554'];
  var message = 'No accounts found';

  if (x.length > 0) {
    message = 'Select an account to display the rewards information: ';
  }

  $('#message').text(message);
  var tableContentHtml = '<table class="table-fill"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Account</th></tr></thead><tbody class="table-hover">';

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tableContentHtml += '<tr><td class="text-left" onclick="goAnotherWebPage(\'' + x[i] + '\')">' + x[i] + '</td></tr>';
  }

  tableContentHtml += '</tbody></table>';
  $(tableContentHtml).appendTo('#container');

  goAnotherWebPage = function(account) {
    console.log(account);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thats exactly how I did it.

Comment: perfect, it works, maybe a dummy question, but this is the very first time I work with jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand what do you need and i create a simple demo for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            var x = ['Visa-1234', 'Amex-9182', 'Visa-8162', 'Visa-9554'];
            var message = 'No accounts found';

            if (x.length > 0) {
                message = 'Select an account to display the rewards information: ';
            }

            $('#message').text(message);

            var tableContentHtml = '<table class="table-fill"><thead><tr><th class="text-left">Account</th></tr></thead><tbody class="table-hover">';

            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                tableContentHtml += '<tr><td class="text-left redirect">' + x[i] + '</td></tr>';
            }

            tableContentHtml += '</tbody></table>';
            $(tableContentHtml).appendTo('#container');
        });

    $('body').on('click', '.redirect', function (e) {
      value = $(this).html();
      console.log(value);
      // do your logic here
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```